# Is the campaign skip only available at character creation?

Tags: diablo-iv

I'm aware that a campaign skip exists in Diablo IV. Once you complete the campaign with one character, other characters are given the option to skip the campaign on character creation. What I'm having trouble finding an answer for online, though, is if campaign skip is accessible *after* character creation.

So if I made a few characters at launch, and then beat the campaign with one of them, would they all be given the option to skip whatever campaign quests they have left? I'm asking since I'd rather not replay the campaign, so I'd hold off on playing with any new characters if campaign skip is a new characters only feature.

**Is the campaign skip only available at character creation, or can it be accessed after character creation as well?**

Comment: A sidestep to this issue would be to re-birth the character as a Seasonal character, when the season starts towards the end of July 2023

Answer (score 1):

The Campaign Skip is available to **all** characters. After you beat the campaign, a campaign skip button will be available during both character creation and at the character selection screen.

Comment: Seems like the answer is present. Can we count this question answered?